# "One from another" or "from one another"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence

Suppose I have a collection of objects (more than two). I wanted to write
"They are at a certain distance one from another".

Someone pointed out I should write
"They are at a certain distance from one another".

However, the second sentence does not sound right to me.

Who is right?

Comment: They are a certain distance apart.

Comment: And then there's also , "from each other"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from%20one%20another%2C%20one%20from%20another&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20one%20another%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20from%20another%3B%2Cc0), *from one another* seems to be significantly more idiomatic than *one from another*:

[image]

*One from another* seems to be preferred over *from one another* by people with a fixation on parsing words in sentences, because the preposition *from* has a clear object: *another* separated from (or influencing) *one*. The meaning of the two expressions is generally interchangeable, but *from one another* seems to have a stronger connotation of **mutual** influence, because of the  precise construction of *one from another*.